# MySQL Qcache_not_cached increases as hit counts increase

Tags: mysql, database

What does **Qcache_not_cached** hold and what is its significance? My **hit_count** increases after every search however **Qcache_not _cached** also **increases**?

Please help me out?

I am using MySql 5.5

Comment: anyone plz help me out....this is to check query performance with and without cache..   Thank you in advance